# Serialize active binding

Tags: r

Is it possible to serialize an active binding "as is", without serializing an environment?

```r
makeActiveBinding(
  sym = "foo",
  env = .GlobalEnv,
  fun = function() cat("Hello\n")
)
foo
#> Hello
saveRDS(foo, "foo-is-not-active-anymore.rds")
#> Hello
rm(foo)
bar <- readRDS("foo-is-not-active-anymore.rds")
bar
#> NULL
```

I would have liked `bar` to print "Hello" as well. The RDS seems to only contain the last value taken by `foo`, that is `NULL` in the example.

I can do the following, but I would prefer to do without the intermediary environment

```r
e <- new.env()
makeActiveBinding(
  sym = "foo",
  env = e,
  fun = function() cat("Hello\n")
)
e$foo
#> Hello
#> NULL
saveRDS(e, "foo-is-active-in-an-environment.rds")
rm(e)
f <- readRDS("foo-is-active-in-an-environment.rds")
f$foo
#> Hello
#> NULL
```

Comment: I don't think an active binding can exist without an environment. In your first example, `bar <- foo` also doesn't work and you are trying to do the equivalent with serialization as a detour.

Comment: Indeed. I am puzzled by _"`makeActiveBinding` installs `fun` in environment `env`"_ in the documentation. I guess what I am actually getting to is: where does the function live? I cannot locate it in `env`. And I don't understand the C source

Comment: It must live in the environment. And you can't find it because there is no static binding to it. I suspect if you really want a good explanation, you'll need to ask on the R-devel mailing list. I can't find any good documentation and this not something I really know anything about.